# Emacs map alternate file ext to .ini syntax highlighting

Tags: emacs, ini

Does anyone know how I might get emacs to apply the ".ini" syntax highlighting for a ".gcf" file (my own custom file ext)?

I've googled, and my best effort was adding to my `~/.emacs`, without joy.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("[.]gcf$" . ini-mode))
```

Comment: actually, that should work just fine (assuming you have ini-mode installed).

Comment: well I think I have as .ini files are displayed with sensible syntax-highlighting

Comment: jtahlborn means that `ini-mode` is not the name of the `.ini` files default mode. So You just have to find out the correct name of the mode - and Your solution will work fine.

Comment: does anyone know the mode name for Conf[Unix], tried the obvious unix-mode but evaling my .emacs still didn;t turn on syntax highlighting for .gcf

Comment: i'm an idiot but eventually figured out its conf-unix-mode - many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find out the mode for `ini` files. While editing a ".ini" file do `C-h m`; then add to your ".emacs" the following code:

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '(".*\.gcf$" . YOUR-MODE) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: actually, the OP's current statement is just fine assuming that they have `ini-mode` installed.

Comment: Note that at the help screen you can follow the "defined in \`foo.el'" link to get to the source code and determine the symbol name for that mode. e.g.: `Conf[WinIni] mode defined in \`conf-mode.el'` takes us to `(define-derived-mode conf-windows-mode conf-mode "Conf[WinIni]" ...)` which means `conf-windows-mode` is what we're after.

Comment: So that means - the mistake was the wrong name of the mode. Hiett'd've bind it to `conf-windows-mode`, not the `ini-mode`.

Comment: its come up as (Conf[Unix]) - thats the same as the text just to the right of all the ---s between the buffer and minibuffer?

Comment: @phils can't quite follow what I have to do to get the text to replace YOUR-MODE. its not just Conf[Unix] is it?

Comment: solution is: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("[.]gcf$" . conf-unix-mode))`

Comment: or just `M-x conf-unix-mode` if you want to manage it manually each time